# How can the list of projects used by Projectile be manually updated?

Tags: projectile

I use the command `locate --regex '/.git$' | grep username` to get a list of all the Git repositories under my $HOME folder.

Is there a way to load them all into `Projectile`, to make them all instantly available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a single project to Projectile's runtime list of known projects (`projectile-known-projects`) using the command `projectile-add-known-project`, which interactively prompts you for the root directory of a project.

In order to add multiple projects at a time, you can use `projectile-known-projects-file`, which is read when `projectile.el` is first loaded. This file can either be modified by hand, or updated with the contents of `projectile-known-projects` using the command `projectile-cleanup-known-projects`. The contents of `projectile-known-projects-file` form a list of project root directories, e.g. `("~/src/emacs/" "~/src/projectile/")`.

ADDENDUM:

You could also write your own function which:

1. calls a custom/external command (like the one you mention) resulting in a sequence of directory paths;
2. adds the resulting directories to `projectile-known-projects`; and
3. (optionally) writes `projectile-known-projects` to `projectile-known-projects-file` for persistence by calling `(projectile-save-known-projects)`.

EDIT (tip for Git and Magit users):

If you use Magit, you can reuse some of its git repository locating functionality (see `magit-repos.el`) in your Projectile configuration. Here's an example from my own configuration:

1. Configure `magit-repository-directories` (which see) to include the desired directories. Note that each entry can be associated with a subdirectory depth. If you organise all your projects as subdirectories of a select few parent directories, then only the parent directories need be added to `magit-repository-directories`, with the corresponding search depth. For example:

   ```el
   (with-eval-after-load 'magit
     (setq magit-repository-directories
           '(;; Directory containing project root directories
             ("~/src/"      . 2)
             ;; Specific project root directory
             ("~/dotfiles/" . 1))))
   ```
2. After Projectile is loaded, you can add all repositories reported by Magit to `projectile-known-projects` using something like:

   ```el
   (with-eval-after-load 'projectile
     (when (require 'magit nil t)
       (mapc #'projectile-add-known-project
             (mapcar #'file-name-as-directory (magit-list-repos)))
       ;; Optionally write to persistent `projectile-known-projects-file'
       (projectile-save-known-projects)))
   ```

(If you use `use-package` you can replace `with-eval-after-load 'projectile` with `use-package projectile :config`.)